# Implementing Timeout. Whats wrong with the following code?

Tags: python, time

The program prints Expired the first time. I am expecting the code to print "not expired"   for atleast 4 times before printing expired. Can someone please explain the reason and help me correct the code. Thank you

```
import time
TIMEOUT =  5

class Timer ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeout = time.time()+TIMEOUT
    def isExpired ():
        return time.time() > self.timeout

timing = Timer()

def main():
    while 1:
        if timing.isExpired:
            print "Expired"
            return
        else:
            print "Not expired"
            print "sleeping for 1 second"
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You did not give your `isExpired` method a self argument.  Define it as `def isExpired(self):`.
2. You are creating a new Timer instance on each loop iteration.  Move the `timing = Timer()` outside the while loop.
3. `timing.isExpired` is a reference to the method object iself (which is always true in a boolean context).  You need to do `timing.isExpired()` to actually call it.

These are all basic Python issues that have nothing to do with `Timer`. Read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to learn how to use classes and so on.

Comment: i get errorTypeError: isExpired() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @user1488987 refer to point number 1. - when you call an instance function you are implicitly giving the instance as the first argument, and the function `isExpired` doesn't accept any arguments at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `Timer` instance everytime. Take it away from loop, or your while loop is never going to terminate. Also, you need to call `timing.isExpired` as it is a method. So your code should be:

```
import time
TIMEOUT = 60 * 5

class Timer ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeout = time.time()+TIMEOUT
    def isExpired (self):
        return time.time() > self.timeout


def main():
    timing = Timer()
    while 1:
        if timing.isExpired():
            print "Expired"
            return
        else:
            print "Not expired"
            print "sleeping for 1 second"
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I took the Timer instance. But the behavior of the program remains the same.

Comment: @user1488987 I tested it and it works. The problem is that timeout is 300 seconds, so you should decrease that number if you're impatient :)